# Django Add new column and assign values based on another table column values

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have a 3 models:

```
class Status(DjangoEnum):
   Status1 = "Status1"
   Status2 = "Status2"
   Status3 = "Status3"

class ABC(models.Model):
   user                    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   variable_1              = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)


class DEF(models.Model):
   abc                    = models.ForeignKey(ABC, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   variable_2             = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)

class GHI(models.Model):
   def                    = models.ForeignKey(DEF, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   variable_3             = models.CharField(
                                   choices=Status.choices(),
                                   default=Status.Status1,
                                   max_length=50,
                             )
```

I want to add a new column "Current_Status"(similar to variable_3 in GHI) in the class ABC. The values that need to be filled in this new column "Current_Status" are based on the values of variable_3 in class GHI.

For example, let's assume that

- Current_Status(in ABC) contains the most frequent value of variable_3(in GHI) among all the records(corresponding to all the DEF records associated with the current ABC record).

How can I add this column so that the existing records in the table ABC are filled with values based on variable_3 in class GHI?